# Is there a way to parse an XML file based on user input in Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, user-input

I have an assignment that requires me to make a console application that can parse an XML file based on user input e.g. to return details of cars manufactured from xxxx-xxxx.

**Java File:**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse("cars.xml");

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

        getNode(doc, xpath);

    }

    private static void getNode(Document doc, XPath xpath) {

        XPathExpression expr;

        Object result = null;

        try {

            //It would be ideal if I could pass int values from Scanner here
            expr = xpath.compile("/cars/car[production-year[. >= 2015 and . <= 2019]]");

            result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getTextContent());
        }

    }

}
```

I've tried using the Scanner class and passing two numbers to Expression but realized it only takes String values.

**XML File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<cars>
    <car id="1">
        <manufacturer>Audi</manufacturer>
        <model>Q3</model>
        <production-year>2011</production-year>
        <horsepower>150</horsepower>
        <consumption type="fuel">7.6</consumption>
        <price>36430</price>
    </car>
    <car id="2">
        <manufacturer>Chevrolet</manufacturer>
        <model>Spark</model>
        <production-year>2013</production-year>
        <horsepower>68</horsepower>
        <consumption>6.6</consumption>
        <price>9995</price>
    </car>
    <car id="3">
        <manufacturer>Aston Martin</manufacturer>
        <model>DB11</model>
        <production-year>2013</production-year>
        <horsepower>510</horsepower>
        <consumption type="fuel">13.5</consumption>
        <price>262908</price>
    </car>
    <car id="4">
        <manufacturer>Volkswagen</manufacturer>
        <model>E-Golf</model>
        <production-year>2017</production-year>
        <horsepower>136</horsepower>
        <consumption type="electric">0</consumption>
        <price>39250</price>
    </car>
    <car id="5">
        <manufacturer>Kia</manufacturer>
        <model>E-Niro</model>
        <production-year>2019</production-year>
        <horsepower>204</horsepower>
        <consumption type="electric">0</consumption>
        <price>43970</price>
    </car>
    <car id="6">
        <manufacturer>Mazda</manufacturer>
        <model>MX-30</model>
        <production-year>2020</production-year>
        <horsepower>145</horsepower>
        <consumption type="electric">0</consumption>
        <price>43970</price>
    </car>
    <car id="7">
        <manufacturer>Mazda</manufacturer>
        <model>MX-5 Roadster Coupe</model>
        <production-year>2013</production-year>
        <horsepower>160</horsepower>
        <consumption type="fuel">11.1</consumption>
        <price>40990</price>
    </car>
    <car id="8">
        <manufacturer>BMW</manufacturer>
        <model>X2 SDrive20i</model>
        <production-year>2018</production-year>
        <horsepower>192</horsepower>
        <consumption type="fuel">6.8</consumption>
        <price>47394</price>
    </car>
    <car id="9">
        <manufacturer>Volkswagen</manufacturer>
        <model>T-Roc</model>
        <production-year>2017</production-year>
        <horsepower>116</horsepower>
        <consumption type="fuel">5.8</consumption>
        <price>29550</price>
    </car>
    <car id="10">
        <manufacturer>Toyota</manufacturer>
        <model>Corolla Sedan</model>
        <production-year>2019</production-year>
        <horsepower>122</horsepower>
        <consumption type="hybrid">3.1</consumption>
        <price>29860</price>
    </car>
    <car id="11">
        <manufacturer>Dacia</manufacturer>
        <model>Sandero</model>
        <production-year>2016</production-year>
        <horsepower>90</horsepower>
        <consumption type="fuel">5.8</consumption>
        <price>14290</price>
    </car>
    <car id="12">
        <manufacturer>Aston Martin</manufacturer>
        <model>V12 Vantage Roadster</model>
        <production-year>2012</production-year>
        <horsepower>517</horsepower>
        <consumption type="fuel">24.3</consumption>
        <price>304951</price>
    </car>
    <car id="13">
        <manufacturer>Fiat</manufacturer>
        <model>500e</model>
        <production-year>2020</production-year>
        <horsepower>95</horsepower>
        <consumption type="electric">0</consumption>
        <price>23900</price>
    </car>
    <car id="14">
        <manufacturer>Toyota</manufacturer>
        <model>GT86</model>
        <production-year>2012</production-year>
        <horsepower>200</horsepower>
        <consumption type="fuel">11.5</consumption>
        <price>57570</price>
    </car>
    <car id="15">
        <manufacturer>Ford</manufacturer>
        <model>Grand C-MAX</model>
        <production-year>2015</production-year>
        <horsepower>125</horsepower>
        <consumption type="fuel">6.4</consumption>
        <price>27695</price>
    </car>
</cars>
```

It doesn't have to be using XPath, I just thought it might work so I went for it but I hit a wall.

Comment: Why Scanner? Why not just use command line parameters?

Answer (score 2):

You are too close!

- You almost reached your target. If you check your `cars.xml` carefully, You can find a way to navigate throw the items in the file. You can use the following `for` loop to navigate your items and see what happens

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    Node carNode = nodes.item(i);
    NodeList carChildNodes = carNode.getChildNodes();

    for (int j = 0; j < carChildNodes.getLength(); j++) {
        Node carChildNode = carChildNodes.item(j);
        if (carChildNode.getNodeType() != Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
            continue;
        System.out.println(carChildNode.getNodeName() + ": " + carChildNode.getTextContent());
    }

    // separate between a car element and another by an empty line
    System.out.println();
}
```

- By running the above code, the output in your console will be:

```
manufacturer: Volkswagen
model: E-Golf
production-year: 2017
horsepower: 136
consumption: 0
price: 39250

manufacturer: Kia
model: E-Niro
production-year: 2019
horsepower: 204
consumption: 0
price: 43970

manufacturer: BMW
model: X2 SDrive20i
production-year: 2018
horsepower: 192
consumption: 6.8
price: 47394

manufacturer: Volkswagen
model: T-Roc
production-year: 2017
horsepower: 116
consumption: 5.8
price: 29550
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

- You can prompt the user in the console to enter `fromYear` and `toYear` by simply inserting this code in your `main` method:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("From Year: ");
int fromYear = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println("To Year: ");
int toYear = scanner.nextInt();
```

Comment: Well that helped with the issue of not having node names before the values but doesn't fix my main issue which is needing a way to let the user enter two numbers (not into code itself but the console) e.g. production-year which determine which cars would appear as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer, wasn't putting proper concatenation when using Scanner input in XPath Expression `[. >= "+ firstNum + " and . <= " + secondNum + "]` I thought it wouldn't be able to apply `>=` and `<=` to `firstNum` and `secondNum`.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse("cars.xml");

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

        getNode(doc, xpath);



    }

    private static void getNode(Document doc, XPath xpath) {

        XPathExpression expr;

        Object result = null;

        try {

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            int firstNum;
            int secondNum;
            System.out.println("Enter first number:");
            firstNum = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter second number:");
            secondNum = scanner.nextInt();

            expr = xpath.compile("/cars/car[production-year[. >= "+ firstNum + " and . <= " + secondNum + "]]");

            result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Node carNode = nodes.item(i);
            NodeList carChildNodes = carNode.getChildNodes();

            for (int j = 0; j < carChildNodes.getLength(); j++) {
                Node carChildNode = carChildNodes.item(j);
                if (carChildNode.getNodeType() != Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                    continue;
                System.out.println(carChildNode.getNodeName() + ": " + carChildNode.getTextContent());
            }

            System.out.println();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: That's a bad solution because it does nothing to prevent injection attacks (where the "number" entered is a maliciously crafted XPath code fragment). Better to include variables in the expression (`/cars/car[prod-year >= $f and prod-year <= $t`) and then supply values for the variables using the XPath variable resolver.